# Define threshold of failures in parameterized test

Tags: java, maven, junit, jenkins, parameterized

We have a parameterized test which generates one test for each file in a specified folder and checks whether we can process it or not.

We expect this parameterized test to fail for a lot of files and that's why we have excluded it from our build process (we're using Maven and Jenkins for CI).

The problem is that because this test is not part of our build, sometimes we accidentally cause more failures than what we expect with code changes.

Does anyone know a way to specify, either in the test itself or in the POM, a threshold and say that if we have more failures than the threshold, this parameterized test should cause the build to fail?

Thank you for all your help.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

what about changing it from a parameterized test to a single test that runs all the files in the list and fails if too many don't work

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot do that! It needs to remain a parameterized test so that we see which files are failing, the reasons and the stacktrace! Also, we want to be able to run just one of these failing tests for debugging purposes!

Comment: Basically it is either that or writing you own `Runner`